# Jackson: unmarshall array of array

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I have the following (what feels like a horror of) piece of JSON

```
[
 ["X", "Y", 0.00010919, 0, null, null, null],
 ["X", "Y", 0.00210919, 0, null, null, null],
 ["A", "B", 0.00310919, 0, null, null, null]
]
```

I'm struggling to get Jackson to parse it let alone work out how to coherently expose that through a POJO.

Any advice?

Comment: What have you tried and exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply parse the array using `Array[Object]` can type cast them to `ArrayList<Object>`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayOfArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Object[] objArr = new Object[0];
        String jsonFilePath = "src/main/resources/arrayOfArray.json"; // JSON File Path
        Object[] mySystems = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File(jsonFilePath), objArr.getClass());

        for (int i = 0 ; i < mySystems.length;i++) {
            ArrayList<Object> list = (ArrayList<Object>)mySystems[i];
            for (Object obj :list) {
                System.out.print(obj + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

if you need to map a JSON to POJO via mappers directly then they should have some struct type JSON in it.
e.g

```
[
 { "field" : "X", "field1" : "Y", ...],
 {"field" : "X", "field1" : "Y", ...],
...
]
```

can be mapped to directly to `Array[CustomBean]`

```
class CustomBean {
 String field;
 String field1;
...
}
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, thanks. My title is slightly wrong. It's really a list of lists.

Comment: if it has solved your problem please consider accepting the answer @DanF